# How can I load VBA customizations stored in a "document-level custom template" into a Map Document created from a "Normal.mxt" template in ArcGIS 10?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcmap, vba

I have all kinds of custom tools that are called from UI Controls stored in a document-level map document (my custom template). In earlier versions of ArcGIS these were stored in the global-level "Normal.mxt". Since this it is no longer possible to save UI controls within the Normal template in version 10 I use the above mentioned map document that has all of my VBA customization to create most of my maps within so that they may "inherit" the customization. This is a very crude solution since it created a problem with maintaining and upgrading my custom tools until i migrate to .NET.

Is there a way to load document-level customization into a map document created from a Normal.mxt template?

Comment: Have you tried overwriting the Normal.mxt file with your custom template?

Comment: Yes. Toolbar menu remains but UI Controls are replaced with some null items that do not have names, icons or code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This cannot done in ArcGIS 10

Answer (score 2):

At 10, you have to install the ArcObjects VBA SDK to use VBA.  You also have to be provisioned a license to use the VBA SDK, which is free.

More info can be found here:  http://events.esri.com/uc/QandA/index.cfm?fuseaction=answer&conferenceId=2F6DC1A1-1422-2418-883C3868A9004888&questionId=3182